# Retina Display Media Query apply on css

Tags: css, resolution, retina-display

I have created a  web application on normal 1440px. Now I have to convert as per specification ,to retina display 2880px. As I have devolved it already. What will easy and best practice of it ?   I tried something like this

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 2800px){
body.checkout-cart-index  input#s_method_flatrate {
    width: 22px;
    height: 12px;
}
}
```

but I came to know now that retina is something different. SO I tried `https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/` this query but I didn't help so far .Maybe I am using it wrongly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't help for you?

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { 

  /* Retina-specific stuff here */

}
```

Comment: I want to change all images to double and spacing of  elements to double. SO I will write 1440px as normal and image width to double in this query ?

Comment: If you write in this query, for example `.image { width: 22px; height: 12px }`, then on retina display your `.image` will has double size

Comment: my height and width on  1440  body.checkout-cart-index  input#s_method_flatrate {
    width: 22px;
    height: 12px;
}   is like this ,   So I am suppose to write  .image {width:42px ; height 24px;}  ? why you wrote same css ?how it will double ?

Comment: Okay okay , and last thing same for padding , margins etc ? or there is something other then this exist ?